# Specific using .on jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have look the code of some library and in the code I have found some strange using of `.on` event.

```
$(document).on('ready.1119.fix', function () {});
```

Could somebody explain me what does it mean? Because I have never seen this before and not sure that it will work. If somebody know how such event construction work, could you explain please?

Comment: Docs: http://api.jquery.com/on. It's a delegated event handler looking for this element: `<ready class="1119 fix"></ready>`. Exactly what a `ready` element is I'm not sure.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thx, got it

Comment: is that the full code? or did you just leave the inner function blank for space?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the horses mouth.

[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Or better still, just leave this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The main differences are

1. `on` works even on dynamically created HTML elements while the `click` doesn't.
2. `on` supports bunch of other parameters while `click` doesn't, like `on("keyup")`
3. `click()` uses more memory as it gets bind on each matching element meaning more memory consumption whereas `on` uses single handler for all the matching elements.

So, there is no functional difference.

**To sum up**

```
$("div").click(function(){
    console.info("hey")
});
```

and this will also do the same thing..

```
$("div").on('click', 'button.alert', function() {
    console.info("hey")
});
```

Note: As of 2021, the recommended way is to go with `on` method.